# Отправить post запрос на сторонний сайт и получить ответ

Tags: post, php, javascript

Реально ли сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки запускался `javascript`, который отправлял бы пост запрос на сторонний сайт и получал ответ? Если нет, то какими методами можно это сделать?

Comment: на сторонний сайт ajax не получится, есть вариант отправить на свой сайт аякс, и оттуда уже через file_gets_content получить данные со стороннего сайта

Answer (score 1):

Можно отправить кроссдоменные запросы через jQuery используя jsoncallback
Например:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ID КНОПКИ').click(function () {
    var param = 'Значение';
    dataString = 'параметр='+ param;
    $.getJSON('http://домен.ru/фаил_обработчик.php?'+ dataString +'&jsoncallback=?', function(json) {
    $("#ID места вывода ответа").html(json.параметр);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

На свой домен и порт - легко через `XMLHttpRequest`.
На сторонние же (даже если порт другой или поддомен) - до недавнего времени было большой занозой в заднице. Сейчас есть [хорошие для этого средства.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Реально. Используйтете в `JS XMLHttpRequest` или используйте фреймворк `jQuery`.

Подобного рода вопросы, на мой взгляд, лучше сначала гуглить.